# Store my local gerrit repository in github

Tags: github, gerrit

I would like to host my gerrit project/repos in github as a backup copy. I would like to store it as public repository. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the [replication plugin](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/replication/+/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md). Given access permissions by the system user running Gerrit, this can mirror to any other Git server (using git, ssh and http(s) as protocols).